# Setup static file in Django from serving site in production mode

Tags: python, html, css, django

I am trying to run my static files from the same serving site in production mode. This is what I did.

In setting.py, I have set,

```
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['12.10.100.11', 'localhost']
```

I included, 'django.contrib.staticfiles' in INSTALLED_APPS

I set the Static root directory to,

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static")
```

I ran,

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

to copy all the static files to a local serving directory.
(following: https://djangobook.com/serving-files-production/)

I then point static url directory to,

```
STATIC_URL = ("/static/")
```

I then run,

```
python manage.py runserver 12.10.100.11:8000
```

However, on console inspect the error shows:

```
**Get http://12.10.100.11:8000/static/css/main.css 404 (not found)**
```

on my base.html looks something like this:

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/css/main.css' %}" type="text/css" />
```

I am new to Django and need lots of advice, thanks

Jef

Comment: As the tutorial says, you have to configure your web server (e.g. Apache or Nginx) to serve the static files. You haven't told us which one you are using, or showed us the configuration. Did the `collectstatic` command work -- was `css/main.css` successfully copied to your `STATIC_ROOT` directory?

Comment: That tutorial is for serving static files using Apache/NginX. It is not recommended to serve your static files using Django on production environment, but if you must do so, have a look at something like whitenoise.

Comment: Thanks Alasdair, I am currently neither using apache or nginx. As Selcuk mentioned I am using my Django on production environment to serve the static files. Collectstatic cmd works perfectly and copied to my static_root directory which is actually a level up from the same django app directory. That is why I was trying to point static_url to where static_root is.

Comment: Thanks Selcuk, will look into whitenoise

Comment: Great whitenoise works perfectly. Its just couple of lines. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't serve static files. django with DEBUG mode turned off isn't responsible for that. Ngnix is better option with chache mechanisms for that.
You should check out Heroku platform how they deploy production ready django projects with whitenoise for example. Github has a lot of examples of opensource projects powered with django that you can learn from

Comment: Thanks Kairat for the advise, will look at deploy production ready django projects with whitenoise.

Comment: Great whitenoise works perfectly. Its just couple of lines. :)

Comment: Only advice i can give is Learn Django Rest Framework for back end with React[Angular,Backbone,...] for front part. It is valuable combination for your future.

Answer (score 1):

1)Pip install whitenoise

2)Include the following lines in wsgi.py

```
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```